# How do I customize the header background color, height, and text of a UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to customize my section headers for a UITableView. How do I add text color, background color, and section header height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){
    view.tintColor = UIColor.black
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50.0
}
```